# Error when running balloons.io

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io

When trying to run the app ,i get this error on terminal

```
node balloons.js
  info  - socket.io started
Balloons.io started on port 8000
Exception: Error: Ready check failed: undefined
   at RedisClient.on_info_cmd (c:\Users\Abhik Lodh\Desktop\Html\balloonchat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\redis\index.js:319:35)
   at Command.callback (c:\Users\Abhik Lodh\Desktop\Html\balloonchat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\redis\index.js:367:14)
   at RedisClient.flush_and_error (c:\Users\Abhik Lodh\Desktop\Html\balloonchat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\redis\index.js:126:25)
   at RedisClient.connection_gone (c:\Users\Abhik Lodh\Desktop\Html\balloonchat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\redis\index.js:423:10)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Abhik Lodh\Desktop\Html\balloonchat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\redis\index.js:91:14)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
   at _stream_readable.js:943:16
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

and the config.json is

```
"redisURL": "http://localhost:8000/",
  "auth": {
    "twitter": {
      "consumerkey" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "consumersecret" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "callback" : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback"
    },
    "facebook": {
      "clientid" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "clientsecret" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "callback" : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    "github": {
      "clientid" : "yourClientID",
      "clientsecret" : "yourClientSecret",
      "callback" : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/github/callback"
    }
  },
  "session" : {
    "secret" : "lms",
    "age" : 14
  },
  "app": {
    "port": 8000
  },
  "theme": {
    "name" : "default"
  }
}
```

i am a newbie in node js. i just extracted the zip from git hub ,followed the instructions but got this error everytime.
i think this error is related to redis but dunno how to fix it

pls help.thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you didn't install Redis or didn't start it. Did you?

```
wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.4.17.tar.gz
tar xvf redis-2.4.17.tar.gz
cd redis-2.4.17
make && make install
```

And then:

```
./redis-server ./redis.conf
```

Comment: i downloaded redis but don't know how to hook it up though i have a client version which runs in the terminal.   would accept any gr8 suggestions on how to run it properly

Comment: Just run those commands in my answer in a different terminal window.